# How Recognize Different View of a single class when i want add it to window

Tags: iphone, ios

Senario like that--
There are three view of a viewcontrollerclass on same level. I want to add one of the view when windowview load.How i added these different view as a subview on windowview .
Suppose i want to add second number of view then how i load it on window ......Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You set the window's `rootViewController`.  There should not be more than one view controller visible at a time- Apple's guidelines expressly state this.  If you want to load another view controller, you can present it modally with `[self pushModalViewController:cnt animated:YES];`.

Additionally, consider reading Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html).

Answer (score 0):

You firstly set the window to viewControllerClass and also load the subViews but in hidden mode then when you need to display subView then hide first view and unhide the subview- view1.hidden = NO;
view2.hidden = YES; 
or you can also remove the view and add another view-
[subview removeFromSuperview];